# In a semidirect product, how can we tell if all complements are conjugate to each other.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose G =  N $\rtimes$ H and $\phi$ is an automorphism on G such that $\phi$(N) = N.  Clearly $\phi$(H) is a complement to N.  Does the order of the first cohomology group $H^{1}$(H,Z(N)) provide information on this?

Edit:

I was interested in complements equivalent under an automorphism of G. For example if N is abelian and $\phi$ is injective then there are conditions for G necessary and sufficient conditions for G to be complete.

(1) N is characteristic in G
 (2) ϕ(H) acts without fixed points on N
 (3) $H^{1}$(H,N) is trivial, and
 (4) ϕ(H) is self normalizing in Aut(N).

I'm trying to understand the role of $H^{1}$(H,N) being trivial plays in this. Clearly if N is not characteristic then G is not complete. Also if ϕ(H) has fixed points in N then G has a non-trivial center and is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are asking. Are you interested in all complements, or just those that are equivalent under an automorphism of $G$?

Note that $A_n$ has about $n/4$ conjugacy classes of complements in $S_n$, one for each cycle type of involutions in $S_n \setminus A_n$. For $n=6$, these two classes of complements are conjugate under an automorphism of $S_6$.

Since $Z(A_n)=1$, so does $H^1(H,Z(N))$, so the order of the cohomology group is not providing any information in this case.

Comment: I was interested in complements equivalent under an automorphism of G. For example if N is abelian and $phi$ is injective then there are conditions for G necessary and sufficient conditions for G to be complete.  1) N is characteristic in G, 2) $\phi$(H) acts without fixed points on N, 3) $H^{1}(H,N)$ is trivial, and 4) $\phi$(H) is self normalizing in Aut(N).  I'm trying to understand the role of $H^{1}$(H,N) begin trivial plays in this.  Clearly if N is not characteristic then G is not complete.  Also if $\phi$(H) has fixed points in N then G has a non-trivial center and is not complete.